# How to attach event with a kendo tabstrip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo tabstrip and a div element (a kendo grid is attached to this grid).
I want to hide the grid whenever any of the tabs are active. When the tabs are collapsed I want to show the grid again.
Here's what I have done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabstrip">
  <ul>
    <li id="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li id="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button class='k-button'>Select second tab</button>
  </div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
  <div id=grid></div>

<script>

   var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: {
       data: [
         {name: "John", age: "20"}
       ]
     }
}).data("kendoGrid");

    var onActivate = function(e) {
    console.log(e.item.id);
    if(e.item.id === "tab1" || e.item.id === "tab2"){
        $("#grid").hide();
    }
  }

  var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    activate: onActivate,
     collapsible: true,
                animation: {
                    open:{
                        effects: "fade"
                    }
                }
  }).data("kendoTabStrip");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to hide the grid on tab click, but how can I show the grid back whenever the tabs are collapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that crosses my mind is to use `select` and check if there is active tabs, it there is no active tabs show grid, otherwise hide it, something like this:

```
var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
  select: function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var active = $(".k-state-active").length;
      if(active) {
        $("#grid").hide();
      } else {
        $("#grid").show();
      }
    }, 0);

  }, 
  collapsible: true...
```

Working example: [Show grid on tab collapse](https://dojo.telerik.com/idOlujuL)